# The project doesn't contain all package namespaces

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, jetbrains-rider

I have created a package and named it `General Utility`. This package has three assembly definition (`.asmdef`) files. Each assembly definition has a specific namespace. You can see the `Root Namespace` field of all assembly definition files in the following:

[image: IO assembly definition]

[image: Network assembly definition]

[image: Command assembly definition]

The namespaces also have been applied to the intended scripts. examples:

[image: Directory is placed within the IO assembly definition]

[image: Core is placed within the Network assembly definition]

[image: ResultModel is placed within the Network assembly definition]

[image: Executor is placed within the Command assembly definition]

[image: CommandModel is placed within the Command assembly definition]

The problem is that when I add (import) the `General Utility` package to my Unity project, project scripts can only see the `Network` assembly definition namespaces. What’s wrong with the others?

[image: The Command and IO namespaces are not displayed.]

Unity version: `2021.3.16`

IDE: `JetBrains Rider`

Comment: Did you reference then in the assembly definition as dependencies?

Comment: Reviewed. The assembly definitions `IO` and `Network` were referenced, but `Command` was not. So I also referenced the assembly definition of `Command`. Now the namespaces `Command` and `Network` are available in my script, but the problem is not yet solved for the namespace `IO`. `IO` is a 'runtime' assembly definition, unlike the others. So maybe that's the problem.
(Actually, I do not need any class of `Command`. I referenced it just for testing purposes.)